File upload to vps server with node js returns the following error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)
I have this code that works perfectly well on localhost and another vps apache server, but for some wierd reason, does not work on a vps server.
the http.conf file is as follows
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName notebook-study.com
    ServerAlias www.notebook-study.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia Full
    Timeout 2400
    ProxyTimeout 2400
    SetEnv proxy-sendchunks  1
    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:4008/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:4008/
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =notebook-study.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.notebook-study.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

When I run my post request with a file in the multipart data, I get the 502 error mentioned above. The file gets uploaded to the desired destination but the other part of the request does not run, for example saving the body of the multipart data. When I run the post request still with multipart/form-data but without a file, it runs just fine and returns the correct response. I have tried all solutions I can find. Someone please help.
I tried to increase the ProxyTimeout from the default value of 60 to 2400. It didn't work
